# Creating new excel file with transformations from existing excel file (using python)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx

I have an xlsx file, df, that contains a large amount of data. I wish to extract data from a particular cell and create a new xlsx file that contains this extracted data, along with a date.

Here is the file, df:

```
    A   B   C                 #headers in excel
 
    1   2   3
```

Desires Output:
I wish to extract the number 3 from C1 (column C, row 1) and then create a new file, df2, which looks like the following -

```
   Date        Value

   1/1/2020    3
```

This is what I am doing:

```
import xlrd                                        #package for working with excel files
import xlwt                                        #allows you to create a new file
df = pd.read_excel(df.xlsx, sheetname="Sheet1")    #reading in my .xlsx file
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)             #one sheet that I am iterating over
sheet.cell(0, 2).value                             #extracting the value in the first row, 2nd column
sheet.write(0, 2)                                  #Inserting data in 1st row and 2nd Column
```

However, I am stuck on adding a particular date within the newly created file

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: You are already reading the sheet with pandas, why are you attempting to change the sheet directly through `workbook`? Make all the changes on the dataframe then save to new file with `.to_excel`

Comment: Ok I see - I am still learning. Let me research this. Makes sense

Answer (score 0):

***openpyxl*** is my favorite library for excel-python process. I've used it into my company project for importing and exporting data from towards excel.

Python library for reading and writing Excel (with extension xlsx/xlsm/xltx/xltm) files.

First, to install this package, you need to terminate this command:

`sudo pip3 install openpyxl`

Let's give you an example for how it works.

**Input Excel File**

[image: Excel Demo Data]

**Python Code**

*Print the first column value*

```py
# importing openpyxl module 
import openpyxl 
  
# Give the location of the file 
path = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\demo.xlsx"
  
# workbook object is created 
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path) 
  
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active 
m_row = sheet_obj.max_row 
  
# Loop will print all values 
# of first column  
for i in range(1, m_row + 1): 
    cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row = i, column = 1) 
    print(cell_obj.value)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
STUDENT 'S NAME
ANKIT RAI
RAHUL RAI
PRIYA RAI
AISHWARYA
HARSHITA JAISWAL
```

***Reference:***
[Reading an excel file using Python openpyxl module](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-reading-excel-file-using-openpyxl-module/)